# Infragistics FilterMenuFormatString

Tags: infragistics

Would someone kindly help me understand this property. Below is their explanation:

---

```
<ig:TextColumn.FilterColumnSettings>
       <ig:FilterColumnSettings FilterMenuFormatString="{}{Regex}"/>
</ig:TextColumn.FilterColumnSettings>
```

When you are applying the format through XAML and using special symbols in it you should escape it with {}.

---

I don't understand how to translate this to a pattern and replace. I'd like to replace the first underscore in the string with a double underscore (trying to defeat the RecognizesAccessKey behavior of the checkbox, without creating a new control template).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The FilterMenuFormatString allows you to apply a FormatString to the values displayed in the filter list similar to what the [String.Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx) method does.

Note that the behavior that you are trying to workaround will be addressed in the Next NetAdvantage for WPF/Silverlight service release which is currently scheduled for April 5th according to the [release schedule](http://www.infragistics.com/help/service-releases/).

If you need to workaround the behavior before then you can use the workaround suggested on the [Infragistics forums](http://www.infragistics.com/community/forums/p/77729/392598.aspx#392598) to set the RecognizesAccessKey of the ContentPresenter to false in the default templates.

Comment: I'm apparently having a very difficult time making myself understood with this question. When you do a regex replace, there is a "pattern" string and a "replace" string. How do you feed the pattern and the replace strings to FilterMenuFormatString? An example would be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Format strings aren't meant to change the values, they are meant to control how those values are displayed.  It may be worth reading more on Formatting Types and the related topics: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/26etazsy.aspx

Comment: That MSDN link would be helpful for formatting date and numeric strings. I'm still unable to figure out how to do a text regex replace, e.g. Find: ([^\_]+)\_(.*) Replace: \1\_\_\2   The Infragistics people were nice enough to give me this example, but it throws exceptions when I try it on my text strings:          <ig:FilterColumnSettings FilterMenuFormatString="{}{^([0-9a-zA-Z]([-\.\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z])*@([0-9a-zA-Z][-\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z]\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,9})$}"/>
      </ig:TextColumn.FilterColumnSettings>

Comment: Changing the value isn't possible using the FilterMenuFormatString property and the best workaround to the issue is to use approach setting the RecognizesAccessKey property of the ContentPresenter to false suggested by Gergana on the forums here: http://www.infragistics.com/community/forums/p/77729/392598.aspx#392598

Comment: Yes, I had been working with Infragistics and it was taking a while for them to grasp what I was trying to do, and for me to grasp what they were trying to say, which is why I came here to stackoverflow for a different kind of help. Thank you for helping.